# To List All System Support Activities in Database

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, database-administration

My superior want me to provide him a list of system support name (based on their id (pc name)) that access to database, what activity that they had performed, which tables, procedures, packages etc that they have changed. Below is my sql :

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME ,A.TERMINAL, A.USERID, STATEMENT, OBJ$NAME, B.MACHINE, B.LOGON_TIME
FROM SYS.AUD$ A , AUDIT_ACTIONS C, V$SESSION B
WHERE C.ACTION = A. ACTION#
AND B.TERMINAL = A.TERMINAL
AND A.TERMINAL LIKE '%ISSD%'
AND TRUNC(B.LOGON_TIME) = '20/OCT/2016' ORDER BY LOGON_TIME;*
```

The results seems not so accurate. Kindly advise and assist me on this.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to cnvert to outer join if needed.

Comment: My support team using MySQL and they have made some changes from back end to our Oracle database.

Comment: Means using    inner join ?

Comment: Are you going to using this query on both MySQL and Oracle?

Comment: yes run both on mysql and oracle.